# Freebsd 10.1: X11 keyboard is english ,how to set to italian?

Tags: freebsd, keyboard-layout

I'm on freebsd 10.1,keyboard of X11 start in english layout,i have edited this file

```
/usr/local/etc/hal/fdi/policy/x11-input.fdi

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<deviceinfo version="0.2">
  <device>
    <match key="info.capabilities" contains="input.keyboard">
      <merge key="input.x11_options.XkbModel" type="string">pc102</merge>
      <merge key="input.x11_options.XkbLayout" type="string">fr</merge>
    </match>
  </device>
</deviceinfo>
```

But still start with us keyboard

Comment: are you actually running hal? Did you try to call setxkbmap from commandline?

Comment: setxkbmap works fine of course,but you can set it only if DE is running not before,hal is running

Comment: what DE are you running? maybe just use the GUI provided by your DE?

Comment: Is your X server configured to use hal? The default now is to use FreeBSD's devd instead, which requires different configuration.

Comment: I have created this file /usr/local/etc/X11/keyboard.conf with those contents `Section "InputClass"
        Identifier              "Keyboard Defaults"
        Driver                  "keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard         "on"
        Option                  "XkbLayout" "it"
        Option                  "XkbVariant" "altgr-intl"
EndSection
` But still english layout

Comment: Try putting those settings in `/usr/local/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/keyboard.conf`. The values you specified look good, so should work if the server can find the config file.

Comment: I put it now in usr/local/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/keyboard.conf but nothing change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I have not personally delved into the furthest extents of UTF-8 character encodings,  but perhaps I may be familiar enough with concepts of POSIX *locale* configurations that I might be able to offer some simple points of reference for this configuration.

There is some advice in the FreeBSD handbook, as towards configuring the FreeBSD *localization* features, in terminal interfaces and in the X.org windowing service. In section 23.4 of the FreeBSD handbook, there is a short example of configuring TTYs and X.org for the Russian KOI8-R character code set [[lang-setup](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/lang-setup.html)]. Section 23.2 of the FreeBSD handbook also provides some more of detail about *localization* features in FreeBSD [[l18n](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/using-localization.html)].

Cross-referencing one FreeBSD FAQ [[faq](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/faq/book.html)] moreover, it seems that the following may be a recommended *locale* identity for the Italian language, as well as for locale-specific features such as for printing of numeric values, dates, etc.

> `it_IT.ISO8859-15`    Italian (Italy)

Referring alternately to the list of files under `/usr/share/locale`, the following *locale* names could also be applied towards localization in the Italian language:

> `it_IT.ISO8859-1`
>
> `it_IT.UTF-8`

Considering that not all fonts might cover all of the Unicode code set (UCS), and considering the relative commonality of ISO-8559-1 encodings, perhaps  `it_IT.ISO8859-1` could be recommended as a *locale* setting, moreover a *locale* setting not requiring support for UTF-8 character encoding.

Referring back to the text of the initial example [[lang-setup](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/lang-setup.html)], I would estimate that the following might be a working configuration entry to add to `/etc/xorg.conf` This configuration entry would be added within the `Keyboard` section of the configuration file:

> `Option "XkbLayout"   "it_IT"`

Alternately, this might suffice as well, without the locale specifier suffixed to the language specifier:

> `Option "XkbLayout"   "it"`

So far as configuring X.org perhaps it might be enough to add that to `xorg.conf` and restart the X server? I hope this helps.

Personally, I'm not aware of what additional fonts might be required, or what additional package/ports selections as in the instance of the UTF-8 locale. I would assume that the ISO-8559-1 locale would be widely supported in applications.

Referring back to section 23.2 of the FreeBSD Handbook, the handbook includes further information as far as how to configure the `LANG` and `MM_CHARSET` environment variables, and configuration properties in the `login.conf` and `/etc/rc.conf` files, for localization [[l18n](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/using-localization.html)].

Comment: there is no xorg.conf

Comment: An `xorg.conf` template can be generated from the shell terminal, using the shell command  `Xorg -configure` -- referencing the [FreeBSD Handbook, section 6.5](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/x-config.html). If I recall correctly, that would generate an appropriate configuration the X.org window server, for the display, keyboard, and pointer hardware installed at the time. Subsequently, the `Keyboard` section in the configuration file may be modified with a text editor, and the file copied to `/etc/xorg.conf`

Comment: I know this,but i want to do like linux,no xorg.conf and use /usr/local/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d

Comment: I'd assume that the X server may at least need a `Keyboard` configuration. I'm not greatly familiar with how the X.org server computes its default configuration.